# Master and topic branch both have changes

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I have a file in my master git branch called 'Readme.'  The file has the following text:

> This is the master branch

I made a topic branch called 'justatest' and edited the 'Readme' file inside of it.  I edited this file (while the justatest branch was checked out) to say the following:

> This is the master branch
>   This text should only be seen in the 'justatest' branch

When I am in the 'justatest' topic branch it appears correctly, but when I switch to the master branch, here's what the file says:

> This is the master branch
>   This text should only be seen in the 'justatest' branch

As you can see, it's making the changes in the master branch even when I have a topic branch checked out!  WHY???

The worst part is that if I don't like the changes I have made in the topic branch and I delete it, the changes REMAIN in the master branch!!  Where's the safety in that???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make edits, they are not part of any branch. These changes are only in your working folder. Changing branches while you have some outstanding work not yet committed is allowed - as long as they don't conflict with the committed version of the files.

In your case it's even simpler. Since you just made the branch, both master and this new branch point to the same commit. Once you add and commit your changes, switching branches will have the behaviour you are expecting.

```
git add -A
git commit -m "my changes"
git checkout master
```

your file will be what it was before you branched.

You can flip between 2 last branches you had checked out by repeatedly doing

```
git checkout -
```

this is also true of `cd`.

Take a look at http://progit.org/book for info about the working directory and index.

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly what the problem was.  I didn't realize I had to commit before switching branches to separate the changes.

Comment: This is actually an awesome feature of git. Gets out of your way any chance it gets. It didn't force you to commit your changes before switching a branch.

Answer (score 1):

If you commit the changes in the topic branch, then you can checkout the master branch and find your changes are only visible in the topic branch until you merge them back to master.

Example:

```
[matthewh@folio temp]$ git branch
* master
[matthewh@folio temp]$ cat Readme 
This is the master branch
[matthewh@folio temp]$ git checkout -b justatest
Switched to a new branch 'justatest'
[matthewh@folio temp]$ echo "This text should only be seen in the justatest branch" >> Readme 
[matthewh@folio temp]$ git commit -am "Modified readme"
[justatest 1afc6c7] Modified readme
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
[matthewh@folio temp]$ git branch
* justatest
  master
[matthewh@folio temp]$ cat Readme 
This is the master branch
This text should only be seen in the justatest branch
[matthewh@folio temp]$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
[matthewh@folio temp]$ cat Readme 
This is the master branch
[matthewh@folio temp]$ git merge justatest
Updating 88aa000..1afc6c7
Fast-forward
 Readme |    1 +
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
[matthewh@folio temp]$ cat Readme 
This is the master branch
This text should only be seen in the justatest branch
```

Comment: I thought my example illustrated that. The merging only showed how to get the justatest branch changes into the master branch.

Comment: one step too many :) That would be a lesson for another day for where the OP is..

Comment: Fair enough - I guess the question of merging was never actually asked :)

Comment: @matthewh - that's where I was headed so thanks for pointing it out.  The branching techniques of git are really starting to make sense now...